# Escape password in mysqldump command

Tags: passwords, mysql

I am using this;

```
mysqldump -u userabc -pabc123 dbname | 
  gzip > /var/backups/archives/mysql/dbname_$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y_\%T).sql.gz
```

This works but if the password contains a `^` for example it fails, how can I escape this character and still have `mysqldump` work with the `-p` flag;

```
mysqldump -u userabc -pabc^123 dbname | 
  gzip > /var/backups/archives/mysql/dbname_$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y_\%T).sql.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quote the password

```
mysqldump -u fred7 -p'asdf^555^666'
```

if any of the following `* ? [ < > & ; ! | $ ( )`  perhaps `^` too

Comment: Note one exception, when using `'` single quotes, the bash shell requires very bizarre escaping if a single quote appears inside the password -- the embedded `'` has to be replaced with 4 consecutive characters `' \ ' '` and not escaped with a simple `\'` as you might expect.

Comment: Nice knowledge @Michael-sqlbot!

Comment: Thanks @DrewPierce. I can confirm that `^` is one of those characters also.